# Any shorter way to compute this integral over the unit ball?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer, and let $V$ be the unit ball centered at the origin. To compute: \begin{equation*}I = \iiint\limits_{V}(x+y+z)^{2n}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}V\end{equation*} I substituted for $x$, $y$, and $z$ with spherical coordinates, did the $r$-integral, then used the binomial expansion on the remaining $((\sin\theta\cos\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi)+\cos\theta)^{2n}$ and integrated the resulting series. Eventually, after a lot of algebra, I got the result \begin{equation*}I = \frac{8 \cdot 3^n \pi(n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+1)}\end{equation*} but I am wondering if there is any shorter way to do this computation. Any suggestions would be appreciated (or explanations as to why no shorter method is possible, if that is the case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rotate this such that:

$u = \frac {1}{\sqrt 3} x +  \frac {1}{\sqrt 3} y + \frac {1}{\sqrt 3} z\\
v = \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} x - \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} y\\
w = \frac {1}{\sqrt 6} x + \frac {1}{\sqrt 6} y - \frac {2}{\sqrt 6} z\\
$

We have an ortho-normal transformation.

It doesn't do anything to the unit ball.  i.e. $u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1$

But the integrand becomes $(\sqrt 3 u)^{2n}$

$\iiint 3^n u^{2n} \ du\ dv\ dw$

Then we can convert to spherical.

$3^n\iiint \rho^{2n+2}\cos^{2n}\phi\sin\phi \ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$

$2\pi 3^n (\frac{1}{2n+3})(\frac {2}{2n+1})$

Which is equivalent to what you have.

Comment: You really only need to specify the $u$-coordinate, the others just ... exist. Anyway, this is surely the way.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, but when I started, I just had to finish... I thought about leaving the others out, but then this felt a little more clear in my mind.

Comment: Of course, it may be better not to leave the customer wondering.